# Selecting pandas dataframe rows with same pair of two column values and different on third for certain number of counts

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've a pandas dataframe of two variables( Begin and End) for three replicates(R1, R2, R3) each of Control(C) and Treatment(T)

```
Begin   End Expt
2   5   C_R1
2   5   C_R2
2   5   C_R3
2   5   T_R1
2   5   T_R2
2   5   T_R3
4   7   C_R2
4   7   C_R3
4   7   T_R1
4   7   T_R2
4   7   T_R3
```

I want to pick up those rows only for which all three replicates of both control and treatment
totally six were observed, i.e (Begin,End:2,5) and not (Begin,End:4,7) as it has only five observations
missing the C_R1.

I've gone through some posts here and tried the following, which works for a small set of sample but I've to test with real data which has around 50K rows

```
my_df[my_df.groupby(["Begin", "End"])['Expt'].transform('nunique') == 6]
```

Please let me know if this is OK or if any better technique exists.
Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. Have you tried to run this on the whole dataset? I suspect it will return in about a second, so the size should not be a challenge. There are probably other ways to get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

```
df[df.groupby(['Begin', 'End'])['Expt']
     .transform(lambda x: (np.unique(x.str.split('_').str[0], return_counts = True)[1] == 3).all())]
 
   Begin  End  Expt
0      2    5  C_R1
1      2    5  C_R2
2      2    5  C_R3
3      2    5  T_R1
4      2    5  T_R2
5      2    5  T_R3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1
df2 = df1[df1.groupby(['Begin','End'])['Expt'].transform('nunique') == 6]
df2
```

| index | Begin | End | Expt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 | 5 | C_R1 |
| 1 | 2 | 5 | C_R2 |
| 2 | 2 | 5 | C_R3 |
| 3 | 2 | 5 | T_R1 |
| 4 | 2 | 5 | T_R2 |
| 5 | 2 | 5 | T_R3 |

Comment: @The August Please ✅ this answer if it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution :)